# Netsuite Advanced PDF Template Issue on Save

Tags: netsuite, erp, suitescript2.0, bfo

It is really annoying, the below snippet was working until last week, something happened on the 2018.2 and its throwing me error when i try to save the Advanced PDF Template.

```
<#if !item.custcolprintonpdf>
```

> The error message on Template is "For "!" right-hand operand: Expected a boolean, but this has evaluated to a hash+string (wrapper: com.netledger.templates.model.StringModel):"

It does not stop there, when i update it to `<#if item.custcolprintonpdf != "true">` the template gets saved, and when i try to print the **Invoice PDF**, it gives me below error.

> Left hand operand is a hash+boolean (wrapper:com.netledger.templates.model.BooleanModel).

Hope this is an Bug, anyone has any work around? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Saw this in the NetSuite Professionals Slack Group:

> I tried doing `<#if item.istaxable>` and it gave an error saying it
>   was a hash+string but then did `<#if item.istaxable == true>` and it
>   worked apparently it doesn't like to use a boolean with a true value
>   to signify truthiness all by itself.

Comment: But still when you try to print the PDF with respective template, it will throw error again.